# exportxml method stops after expor of 30% of a table, 3GB internal memory, 3TB disk, no runtime errorcode. on other machine it works perfect

Tags: vba, ms-access

exportxml method (VB-ACCESS) suddenly stops after exporting some 30% of a table, (3GB internal memory, 3TB disk, Win10, 64biy, MS-Access 2019), without even running into an errorcode. on other machine it works perfectly. any ideas?

looked at MS blogs etc, none of the proposed solutions are applicable

```
ChDir PEPDir & "\" & Bedrijf
'XML file exporteren
   Application.ExportXML _
   ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
   DataSource:="PEPCOut", _
   DataTarget:="PEP-ProManIT-" & MaakDate & ".xml", _
   SchemaTarget:="PEP-ProManIT-Schema-" & MaakDate & ".xsd"
```

expect 1mio+ records to be exported, only some 300K+ are exported